# Change article date format

Tags: 8, datetime

I'd like to change the date format that is used for articles in Drupal 8. It looks like it uses the `Default medium date` format by default. I added my own format at `admin/config/regional/date-time`, but I  can't find where to edit the format that articles use.

Is there a way to do this from the CMS or does this need to be done in code?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So after spending more time than I care to admit looking into this, I've come up with two solutions to this.

**Solution 1**

One way to do it is with the date function that darol100 mentioned in his answer. Modifying his example for my case, in my `node--article.html.twig` file, I changed:

```
{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
```

to

```
{% set createdDate = node.getCreatedTime|date('j F Y') %}
{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ createdDate }} {% endtrans %}
```

The advantage to this approach is that it's easy and quick. The disadvantage is I'm not using Drupal's built-in date format system.

**Solution 2**

In order to use Drupal's date format system, I first created my custom format at `admin/config/regional/date-time`. Then I edited `node--article.html.twig` as follows:

```
{% set createdDate = node.getCreatedTime|format_date('my_custom_format') %}
{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ createdDate }} {% endtrans %}
```

This assumes I named my custom format "**My Custom Format**", which results in the machine name `my_custom_format`.

While this solution requires an extra step, I feel it's the more Drupal way to do it.

I learned about it on this page about [Drupal's Twig Filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357633).

Comment: Great answer! For some reason, my custom date format isn't working and I'm getting what appears to be a literal interpretation of the string that my custom format name spells. I copied the machine name directly from my config just to be sure I didn't make a typo. I assume you've tried this feature? 


For "article_short_date", I'm getting: "pmWed, 20 May 2020 14:20:00 -050031202020-05-20T14:20:00-05:00WednesdayAmerica/Chicago_00022020Wed, 20 May 2020 14:20:00 -050031_20pm31America/Chicago"

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize solution 2 changes to a different method, from date() to format_date()

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the date format base on article content type level. You can edit/add the following code `post.published_at|date` and use a filter to alter the date format.

**node--article.html.twig**

```
{# Here are few example #}
{{ post.published_at|date(format='j  F  Y') }} {# Output = 10 March 2001#}
{{ post.published_at|date(format="F j, Y, g:i a") }} {# Output = March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm#}
{{ post.published_at|date(format='m/d/Y') }} {# Output 10/3/2001 #}
```

Twig use the same naming code as [php date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
For more information about twig date formats visit - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Comment: Thumbed up! darol100, Can this be done in TPL files in a same manner for someone with Drupal 7 site?

Comment: Yes, but is uses PHP template instead of twig syntax. It should looks something too this  `<?php print format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm/d/y'); ?>`.

Comment: Thanks darol100, this was quite useful in helping me learn about Twig filters. Ultimately, however, I went with using the format_date filter that Drupal provides (as I show in my answer).

Answer (score 10):

I'm more for Chris's solution 2. As he says it IS more the drupal way... but it's not the best option yet.

format_date() has been deprecated and will be removed before Drupal 9... meaning that one day, you'll do a drupal update and this will break.

Instead, it's better to do this in your .theme file in a preprocess function.

```
function [theme_name]_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['date'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($variables['node']->getCreatedTime(), 'my_custom_format');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to find the date format already in use, and just change that in the UI. Just compare what you see on the page with the date formats in `admin/config/regional/date-time/`

If you change eg "Default medium date" it will change the dates using this format without touching any template/twig files.

Date formats can also be set/translated per language for multi language setup.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: This did not work for me. Default medium date had no effect on the date display although it was exactly the same format. I have also a "fallback" date format that I can't edit nor delete.

Comment: I would guess that the date format is overwritten by a twig template or views, or you are facing some language problems mentioned here https://www.drupal.org/node/2896235

Answer (score 2):

An observation about what Duke said:

> format_date() has been deprecated and will be removed before Drupal 9...

Yes, Drupal function [format_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/8.2.x) defined in *core/includes/common.inc* is, in fact, deprecated. But, when you use the twig filter *format_date()* you are NOT calling that Drupal function, instead of that you are using the twig filter defined by Drupal in
[TwigExtension::getFilters()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3AgetFilters/8), and this filter calls [DateFormatter::format()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Datetime!DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8).

Hence, using the twig filter *format_date()* is safe and Chris's solution 2 is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the format in node.html.twig like this:

```
{{ node.createdtime|date(format="Y-m-d") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Submitted By field by using Display Suite to create a Token Field.

In Drupal 8  /structure/ds/fields

Then add a field using html and tokens like...

```
By [node:author] on [node:created:custom:F j, Y]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that I change only the characters of the date but not any surrounding HTML elements, I use the following hook:

```
function [theme_name]_preprocess_field(array &$variables) {
  if ($variables['field_name'] === 'created') {
    $timestamp = $variables['element']['#items']->value;
    $markup = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($timestamp, 'html_date');
    $variables['items'][0]['content']['#markup'] = $markup;
  }
}
```

Replace `[theme_name]` with the name of your theme and `html_date` with your desired time format, one of those you find under `/admin/config/regional/date-time`.

Answer (score -1):

You can have all the formats PHP for Date and Time

```
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)


{% set createdDate = node.getCreatedTime|date('F j, Y, g:i a') %}
<div class="newsSingleAuthorDate">
      {% trans %}Submitted by <span>{{ author_name }}</span>  on {{ createdDate }} {% endtrans %}
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I used the following code for node--article--full.html.twig :

```
<li class="post-date">
    {% set day = node.createdtime|date("d") %}
      <span class="day">{{ day }}</span>
    {% set month = node.createdtime|date("M") %}
        <span class="month">{{ month }}</span>
 </li>


{% set date = node.createdtime|date("M d, Y") %}
   <span>{{ date }}</span>
```